# Securing Rest API content using .Net Identity Framework

Tags: rest, api, identity

Can anyone provide direction on how to add a Rest API to an existing Azure .net website as an alternative to receive private information? Like many website, we already have good U&P authentication via .Net Identity Framework over SSL to protect the U&P and content.

There are a lot of .net C# websites that have implemented the .net U&P framework that works great over SSL.  With the proliferation of Rest APIs, we need to provide these users capability to login with their already existing credentials via Rest API so how can we simply extend this?

Comment: Hi Walter, and welcome to Security.SE.  I think you may have better luck asking your question on a different StackExchange site, such as StackOverflow, since this is a programming based question rather than a security question as defined by the help center.